# Android Intent without changing view

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to create an Intent that starts another app but i do not want it to change views and open the app listed in the intent. I want it to open within my app essentially.

Comment: Initially I would think that's crazy but that's actually what the `Slices` API is for, introduced in Android 9.0, see [official page](https://developer.android.com/guide/slices/) (or at least that's what I think. I'm reading it too just to make sure)

Comment: If you are not trying to show the UI of the other app, what does "starts another app" mean?

Comment: You mean "Start another app" but not show  ?? Could you plz give us some demo  ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm assuming he expects it to open kinda like a WebView inside his own layout stuff. But I don't know enough about Slices to know if it's possible with Slices.... in fact, Slices seem to be more confined (also Android API 28+ only). So I guess that's not what it's for then. Ah well

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Slices work back to API Level 19 or so via the AndroidX libraries. However, approximately zero apps have implemented slices at the moment.